# VB.Net - ListView with image from URL

Tags: vb.net, listview

So i want to add images from URL to my listview.

This is my code so far, yet it works only on images from PC and i have no idea how to make it work with images from url.

```
'Outside subs
Dim imgList As New ImageList

'On form load
ListView1.Columns.Add("Picture", 53, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
ListView1.Columns.Add("Username", 145, HorizontalAlignment.Left) '163
ListView1.AllowColumnReorder = True
ListView1.Columns(1).DisplayIndex = 1
imgList.ImageSize = New Size(48, 48)
imgList.Images.Add("Picture", Image.FromFile("C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads\image.png"))
ListView1.SmallImageList = imgList

'On button
Dim index As Integer = 0
Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
lvi.ImageIndex = index
lvi.SubItems.Add("text")
ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
```

Comment: You have to download the images to your computer. You can do that manually or you can do it in code. There are different ways to do it in code for example using `System.Net.HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks!